# AngularJS: How to calculate distance between 2 div and hide current top scrolling div?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have div in head (main), and i need to calculate distance between 2 div, when user scrolling ".all" div. If current div "elems" seen only half, i need to hide this current "elems" div.

```css
.main {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
.all {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    overflow: auto;
}
.elems {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>

<div class="all"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>

    
<div>
```

Please, see scree, how it should look https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjcVR.png

Comment: Distance in which direction, y? Are you using jQuery? You need to calculate distance between which two divs?  Have tried bounding boxes or offset from top?

Comment: Yes, i'm using jquery. Please, see screen http://i.imgur.com/NpFEOCs.png

Comment: So you want to hide divs underneath main?

Comment: Read this: http://api.jquery.com/offset/ . Just calculate main's offset and add height then compare it with elems' offset.

Comment: Thank you, but jquery offset not working with My Angular App.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that? If yes you got little bit wrong aproach.
I think you shouldn't use that load of 
's. As far as i'm concerned you shouldn't position div on top of another using float:left clear:both.

```js
var mainRef = $("#main")
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $.each($(".elems"),function(index,element){
    if(mainRef.offset().top+mainRef.height() > element.offset().top + element.height() ){
      //DO YOU STUFF HERE
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.main {
    width: 502px;
    height: 110px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    background: red;
    left:9px
}
.all div:first-child{
    margin-top:100px
}
.all {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
}
.elems {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>

<div class="all">
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>
    <div class="elems"></div>

    
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i don't need it. if the upper part of the each ".elems" block is hidden under top of parent block, 
i need to completely hide this div (display: none, for example).

Comment: Ok.. Sry that i missunderstood you. Try it now. It should be something like that.